# Java stream group by inner array

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have lists of objects of Class below:

```
class Response {
     public String shortName; 
     public String[] types;
}
```

I want to do group by operation on types using streams.
e.g.  If I given a list of Responses like below
`[{"Alaska", ["state", "admin level1"]}, {"New Jersey", ["state", "admin level2"]}]`
Result should be map like :

```
{"state":["Alaska", "New Jersey"], "admin level1": ["Alaska"], "admin level2": "New Jersey"}
```

Comment: Have you tried a non-stream way?

Comment: Such questions work out much better when you include your efforts...+

Comment: I think for this kind of Questions there are no alternatives, either you get it or no. I have tried without group by and it works, I want to know Group by way. There is no point in posting without group by way as question is specifically about group by

Comment: how this `[{"Alaska", ["state", "admin level1"]}, {"New Jersey", ["state", "admin level2"]}]` json be list of response

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`map` the string array in each `Response` into a `SimpleEntry`, flatten that and apply `groupingBy` with a `mapping` as the downstream collector.

```
Map<String, List<String>> resultSet = 
      responses.stream()
               .flatMap(e -> Arrays.stream(e.getTypes()).map(a -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(a, e.getShortName())))
               .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
                        Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, 
                                            Collectors.toList())));
```

if you want the result in the order shown in your post then you'll want to dump the result into a `LinkedHashMap`:

```
...
...
.collect(Collectors.groupingBy(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getKey,
       LinkedHashMap::new, // a supplier providing a new empty map into which the results will be inserted
       Collectors.mapping(AbstractMap.SimpleEntry::getValue, Collectors.toList())));
```

Comment: I'd say it's slightly perverse to put the key/value into the entry in that order: you are making a map keyed by the type, so may as well put the type as the key here. Not that it *really* matters, as the entry is very short lived.

Comment: @AndyTurner sure thing, whatever makes the community happy, I've switched them around ;-).

Comment: @Aomine I wouldn't class myself as speaking for the community. Just a suggestion.

Comment: You don’t need to refer to `AbstractMap.SimpleEntry` in the method references. Just use `Map.Entry::getKey` and `Map.Entry::getValue`. This simplifies future changes, e.g. when you switch to Java 9 or newer and replace `new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(…)` with `Map.entry(…)`.